# MVVM WPF Adding TabItem From Another TabItem's Content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Hi there and sorry for the long post.I hope nobody asked the same question. If so, I ask for your excuses.
I have a problem with adding a `TabItem` dynamicly, from another `TabItem`'s content, witch is `UserControl`, using MVVM approach.
The `MainWindow` has a viewmodel class binded called `TabsMainViewModel`:

```xaml
<Window x:Name="Main" x:Class="Interface_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Interface_test"
        xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Interface_test.Customers"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="850" Width="825" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:TabsMainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate">
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" 
                    Background="Transparent" 
                    Name="btnDelete" 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                    Padding="0"  
                    Command="{Binding RemoveItemCommand}">
                <Image Height="11" Width="11" Source="Images/closeButton.png"/>
            </Button>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabItemContent" >
        <UserControl Content="{Binding TabContent}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<TabControl  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemTemplate}"
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TabItemContent}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"  
                 Name="tcMDI" 
                 Visibility="Visible"  
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  >
```

In the `TabsMainViewModel` I have one `ObservableCollection` of a custom class called `TabViewModel`.

```csharp
public class TabsMainViewModel
    {
        int tabCounter;
        private Dictionary<string, string> _openedTabs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public TabsMainViewModel()
        {
            this.Tabs=new ObservableCollection<TabViewModel>();
            //this.AddItem(null);
        }
        public ObservableCollection<TabViewModel> Tabs
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public ICommand CustomerSearch
        {
            get
            {
                CustomerSearch f = new CustomerSearch() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab1", Title = "Customer Search" };
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate { this.AddItem(f); });
            }

        }
        public ICommand Customer
        {
            get
            {
                Customer f = new Customer() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab2", Title = "Customer" };
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate { this.AddItem(f); });
            }

        }
        public ICommand EmployerSearch
        {
            get
            {
                CustomerSearch f = new CustomerSearch() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab3", Title = "Employer Search" };
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate { this.AddItem(f); });
            }
        }
        public ICommand Employer
        {
            get
            {
                Customer f = new Customer() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab4", Title = "Employer" };
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate { this.AddItem(f); });
            }

        }
        public void AddItem(ITabContent userControl)
        {

            if (_openedTabs.ContainsKey(userControl.UniqueTabName))
            {
                foreach (TabViewModel tvm in Tabs)
                {
                    if (userControl.UniqueTabName == tvm.TabContent.UniqueTabName)
                    {
                        tvm.IsSelected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TabViewModel tabItem = new TabViewModel(this) { TabContent = userControl };
                tabItem.TabContent.Title += " " + tabCounter;
                tabItem.IsSelected = true;
                Tabs.Add(tabItem);
                _openedTabs.Add(tabItem.TabContent.UniqueTabName, tabItem.TabContent.Title);
                tabCounter++;
            }

        }
        public void RemoveItem(TabViewModel tabItem)
        {
            this.Tabs.Remove(tabItem);
            _openedTabs.Remove(tabItem.TabContent.UniqueTabName);
            tabItem.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

The `TabViewModel` Class, I have:

```csharp
public class TabViewModel:ObservableObject,IDisposable
    {
        private bool _isSelected;
        private ITabContent _tabContent;
        private readonly TabsMainViewModel tabsMainViewModel;

        public TabViewModel(TabsMainViewModel tabsMainViewModel)
        {
            this.tabsMainViewModel = tabsMainViewModel;
            this.tabsMainViewModel.Tabs.CollectionChanged += this.Tabs_CollectionChanged;


            this.RemoveItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(
                delegate
                {
                    this.tabsMainViewModel.RemoveItem(this);
                },
                delegate
                {
                    return this.tabsMainViewModel.Tabs.Count > 1;
                }
                );
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.tabsMainViewModel.Tabs.CollectionChanged -= this.Tabs_CollectionChanged;
        }
        private void Tabs_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RemoveItemCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        public DelegateCommand RemoveItemCommand { get; set; }

        public ITabContent TabContent
        {
            get { return _tabContent;}
            set
            {
                _tabContent = value;
                _tabContent.Parent = this;
                Header = value.Title;
            }
        }
        public String Header
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return this._isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (this._isSelected != value)
                {
                    this._isSelected = value;
                    RaisePropertyChangedEvent("IsSelected");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the `TabContent` Property I set a `UserControl` that appears in the `TabItem`'s content. My question is: How can I put a button in this `CustomerSearch` usercontrol, and that button to bind something like `ICommand` or `DelegateCommand` (in its `CustomerSearchViewModel` for example) that can execute the `AddItem` function in `TabsMainViewModel`?

If needed I can post and the `ObservableObject` and `DelegateCommand` classes
and `ITabContent` interface.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, never ever implement the `Dispose()` method like you did it for the `TabViewModel` class. This method can be called by garbage collector in a nondeterministic way, that means - you cannot know when, how many times and by which thread it will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind. Any suggestions about the question I've asked? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kind a solve my problem. I'll post the solution, for double check, and if someone has the same problem. So the solution is:

Add a class that is the `CustomerSearch`'s viewmodel called `CustomerSearchViewModel`. In this class you add a delegate function, and an event that is registered in the `TabsMainViewModel`:

```csharp
namespace Interface_test.Customers
{
    public delegate void OpenNewTab(ITabContent uc);
    class CustomerSearchViewModel
    {
        public static event OpenNewTab AddNewCustomerTab = delegate { };
        public CustomerSearchViewModel()
        {

        }
        public ICommand ShowCustomer
        {
            get
            {
                Customer f = new Customer() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab12", Title = "Customer from search" };
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate {AddNewCustomerTab(f); });
            }

        }

    }
}
```

In the main viewmodel `TabsMainViewModel` where I create an instance of the UserControl, I register the event:

```csharp
public ICommand CustomerSearch
        {
            get
            {
                CustomerSearch f = new CustomerSearch() { UniqueTabName = "NewTab1", Title = "Customer Search" };
                CustomerSearchViewModel.AddNewCustomerTab += AddItem;
                return new DelegateCommand(delegate { this.AddItem(f); });
            }

        }
```

I do not know if this is the right approach, but it worked for me. If someone has best solution, do not hesitate to share it.

Best Regards,

Julian